# How to change a Ackermann function to void return type in C++

Tags: c++

Having the following code,

```
int Ack(int m, int n)
{
   if (m==0)
      return n+1;
   else if (n==0)
      return Ack(m-1,1);
   else
      return Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1));
}


int main() {
    int k = Ack( 2, 2 );
     cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change the return type of Ack() from int to void so that result value can be stored into the variable k correctly? Like using pass by reference but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: If you change from `int` to `void` then the function cannot return anything.

Comment: If you change it to `void`, you won't be able to get a result in `k`.

Comment: You could pass `k` by reference and update it inside the function.  But that is an antipattern and will make the code more confusing.

Comment: *"so that variable k can contain the result value correctly"* Could you elaborate on that? Is there an overflow?

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess OP's real problem is *how* to calculate and represent [that result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted function works as expected for *small* values of the parameters, like the `Ack( 2, 2 );` in the example, which returns `7`.

The problem is the very nature of the [Ackerman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) itself (or the two-argument Ackermann–Péter function, which seems to be the one used here). I won't pretend to know the theory behind, so I'll quote (and emphatize) some of the relevant parts of the Wikipedia page:

> In computability theory, the Ackermann function, named after Wilhelm Ackermann, is one of the simplest and earliest-discovered examples of a total [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) that is **not** [primitive recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). All primitive recursive functions are total and computable, but the Ackermann function illustrates that not all total computable functions are primitive recursive.
>   [...]
>   Its value grows rapidly, even for small inputs. For example, A(4, 2) **is an integer of 19,729 decimal digits** (equivalent to 2<sup>65536</sup>−3 ...).
>   [...]
>   It may not be immediately obvious that the evaluation of A(*m*, *n*) always terminates. However, the recursion is bounded because in each recursive application either *m* decreases, or *m* remains the same and *n* decreases. Each time that *n* reaches zero, *m* decreases, so m eventually reaches zero as well. (Expressed more technically, in each case the pair (*m*, *n*) decreases in the lexicographic order on pairs, which is a well-ordering, just like the ordering of single non-negative integers; this means one cannot go down in the ordering infinitely many times in succession.) However, **when *m* decreases there is no upper bound on how much *n* can increase and it will often increase greatly**.

An `int` simply can't store such big numbers, so if you want to performe those calculations you need to use an arbitrary precision (often called bignum) arithmetic library like [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) or the kinds, and follow their API.

That would solve only one of the issues, though, the other beeing the extremely big number of recursive calls. The same wiki page mention its [use as benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Use_as_benchmark).

This [Rosetta Code's page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#C.2B.2B) shows a more efficient implementation, which basically tries to avoid most of the recursive calls with a closed form calculation of the small *m* cases.